# ImportDataSource function failed from SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with Win10 x64, SQL Server 2017 x64, JyputerNotebook and using primary RevoScalePy library.

I can establish a connection to my local server, create db, query a table etc.
However, when I define a function returning a bytestream of a image and call this function as follows:

```
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from revoscalepy import RxInSqlServer, rx_exec

# create a remote compute context with connection to SQL Server
sql_compute_context = RxInSqlServer(connection_string=connection_string.format(new_db_name))

# use rx_exec to send the function execution to SQL Server
image = rx_exec(send_this_func_to_sql, compute_context=sql_compute_context)[0]

# only an image was returned to my jupyter client. All data remained secure and was manipulated in my db.
display.Image(data=image)
```

...I get an error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
>   'NB-IT-JIRAK\SJ01'.
>
> ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect
>
> Could not open data source. ImportDataSource function failed. Please
>   see the console output for more information.

I follow this tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mlserver/2018/07/10/run-r-and-python-remotely-in-sql-server-from-jupyter-notebooks-or-any-ide/
I've tried to create a new DNS for SQL Server ODBC 17 driver beside my MS Access Driver in Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Data Sources.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Login failed for user 'NB-IT-JIRAK\SJ01'` means that your Windows identity failed to logon to SQL Server.  This could be because you lack permissions, or because the database specified in your connection string does not exist.  The SQL Server log will have the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to import data from SQL Server, right.  Try it this way.

```
import pypyodbc 
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=Server_Name;"
                        "Database=DB_Name;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

#cursor = cnxn.cursor()
#cursor.execute("select * from Actions")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Actions')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Here are a couple resources to brows through in your spare time.

http://pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/03/11/python-and-data-sql-server-as-a-data-source-for-python-applications.aspx

Comment: I'm using both pyodbc and revocalepy. However, it's revoscalepy lib I want to uuse in order to be able set a compute scope to the server, so I don't download and process any data - just printing final image.

Comment: Hummm, I don't know about that.  Hopefully someone will post a solution here so we can all learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (trusted connectionstring)

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(''DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER={server_name};DATABASE={db-name};Trusted_Connection=True;'')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("EXECUTE [dbo].[PyPlotMatplotlib]")
```